# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while opening stream from SSL-secured WSDL

Tags: web-services, tomcat, ssl, indexoutofboundsexception

I get a confusing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at every SSL-secured Webservice call and I have no idea what's the reason. The exception comes without any relevant change on the code over night and I am baffled.

Can anyone give me a hint how I can fix this shitty bug?

Environment:

- Tomcat7
- IBM JDK 6

Stacktrace:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:132)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:184)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:137)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:144)
    at $Proxy294.liefereKonfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at at.gv.bmf.efsz.vkps.client.lieferekonfiguration.impl.LiefereKonfigurationServiceClientImpl.updateKonfReader(LiefereKonfigurationServiceClientImpl.java:279)
    at at.gv.bmf.efsz.vkps.client.lieferekonfiguration.impl.LiefereKonfigurationServiceClientImpl.initiateUpdate(LiefereKonfigurationServiceClientImpl.java:205)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy293.initiateUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at at.gv.bmf.efsz.vkps.client.lieferekonfiguration.impl.VKPSClientInitializer.initVKPSClient(VKPSClientInitializer.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.ibm.jsse2.n.a(n.java:27)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:328)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:386)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:278)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:298)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.startHandshake(tc.java:337)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:23)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:57)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1024)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:56)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:120)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.TlsPrfGenerator.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.TlsPrfGenerator.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.TlsPrfGenerator.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.TlsMasterSecretGenerator.engineGenerateKey(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.b(gb.java:268)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.a(gb.java:131)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:216)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:71)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.n(gb.java:142)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.a(gb.java:95)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:244)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.g(tc.java:206)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:165)
    ... 60 more
```

Comment: Same issue with Websphere 8.5, Jersey 1.12. Web service call works fine without SSL

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are using [IBMJSSE2 Provider](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/ibmjsse2.html) for SSL Communication.

There is a very similar problem which is already fixed:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1IV73472

> APAR Name: IV73472: LARGE PRE-MASTER SECRET GENERATED FROM 2048 BIT DH KEY NOT DIGESTED IN TLSV1 AND TLSV1.1
>
> Problem summary: When TLSv1 or TLSv1.1 was used, the large pre-master secret
>   generated from 2048 bit DH key was not properly hashed to derive
>   the master secret.
>
> Local fix: Disable cipher suites which uses DH/DHE key exchange.
>
> Problem conclusion: A fix is made to IBMJSSE2 and IBMJCE provider to handle large pre-master secret in TLSv1 and TLSv1.1
>   The associated Hursley RTC Problem Report is 93670 and 94644
>   The associated Austin CMVC defect is 116692 and 116765
>   JVMs affected: Java 6.0, Java 626, Java 7.0, Java 727 and Java 8
>   The fix was delivered for Java 6.0 SR16FP7, Java 626 SR8FP7,
>   Java 7.0 SR9FP10, Java 727 SR3FP10 and Java 8 SR1FP10
>   The affected jar are "ibmjsseprovider2.jar" and
>   "ibmjceprovider.jar".
>   The build level of ibmjceprovider.jar for the affected releases
>   is "20150604".
>   The build level of ibmjsseprovider2.jar for the affected
>   releases is "20150604"

Try to upgrade ibmjsseprovider2.jar library.